# Impossible to change the src attribute using img.src

Tags: javascript, html, src

I have a problem using the property .src, I'm meant to use it to change images on every load of the html page using random generated numbers. And for some reason, the img.src doesn't change the src property of the targeted id and stop my loop "for" for some reasons... (The code is run on a separate file form HTML) Here is the js code :

```
const images_for_you = [
    './assets/Series/Aggretsuko.jpg',
    './assets/Series/AngelBeast.jpg',
    './assets/Series/Arcane.jpg',
    './assets/Series/BreakingBad.jpg',
    './assets/Series/BlackMirror.jpg',
    './assets/Series/BluePeriod.jpg',
    './assets/Series/Django.png',
    './assets/Series/GreatPretender.jpg',
    './assets/Series/Hilda.jpg',
    './assets/Series/JeVeuxMangerTonPancreas.jpg',
    './assets/Series/LaLigneVerte.jpg',
    './assets/Series/LeCupheadShow.jpg',
    './assets/Series/LesEnfantsDeLaBalaine.jpg',
    './assets/Series/LeVoyageTeChihiro.jpg',
    './assets/Series/QuoiQuilArriveJeVousAime.jpg',
    './assets/Series/NosMotsCommeDesBulles.jpg',
    './assets/Series/SkyHighSurvival.jpg',
    './assets/Series/toradora.jpg',
    './assets/Series/SkyHighSurvival.jpg',
    './assets/Series/Viking.jpg']; // 20
const images_japanese_animation = [];
const images_netflix_originals = [];
const images_films_sf = [];
const images_studios_ghibli = [];
const images_dessins_animes = [];

function random_array(iterations){
    var randomArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i<iterations; i++){
        randomArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*iterations))
    }
    return randomArray
}

function attribute_for_you(number_of_images){
    let randArr = random_array(number_of_images)
    let index_for_you = [
        'for_you_1',
        'for_you_2',
        'for_you_3',
        'for_you_4',
        'for_you_5',
        'for_you_6',
        'for_you_7',
        'for_you_8',
        'for_you_9',
        'for_you_10',
        'for_you_11',
        'for_you_12',
        'for_you_13',
        'for_you_14'
    ]
    
    for (let i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++){
        console.log(images_for_you[randArr[i]])
        console.log(randArr[i])
        console.log(i)
        var img_index = document.getElementsById(index_for_you[i])
        img_index.src = images_for_you[randArr[i]]
    } 
}
attribute_for_you(10)
```

Thanks for your help
Also, the ids are correct, i checked it multiple times :)

Comment: and what error are you getting?

Comment: That's the weird thing, i get no error, it just change nothing

Comment: My bad, here it is : Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function
    at attribute_for_you (main.js:68:34)
    at main.js:72:1

Comment: Are you sure that img_index variable is actually an img html element? I think it's not. You've got a syntax error. Instead of document.getElementsById you should use document.getElementById.

Comment: yup here it is the html code 
<div>
        <div class="w-72">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/watch/80198377"><img class="w-72 rounded" src="./test" id="for_you_1"></a>
      </div>
</div>

Comment: Although I got a new error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')
    at attribute_for_you (main.js:69:23)

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with any given `id`, it must at all times be unique. That is why **there is no getElement*s*ById**, only `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You also need to add those image elements to your HTML body if they are not in your HTML

```
for (let i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++){
        console.log(images_for_you[randArr[i]])
        console.log(randArr[i])
        console.log(i)
        var img_index = document.getElementById(index_for_you[i])
        //if cannot find that image element, we need to add it
        if(!img_index) {
          imageElement = document.createElement('img');
          imageElement.setAttribute("id", index_for_you[i]);
          //add the image element to the body
          document.body.appendChild(imageElement);
        }
        img_index = document.getElementById(index_for_you[i])
        img_index.src = images_for_you[randArr[i]]
    }
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You have syntax error here

```
var img_index = document.getElementsById(index_for_you[i])
```

It should be `getElementById`, not `getElementsById` (`Elements` should not have `s`)

The change should be

```
var img_index = document.getElementById(index_for_you[i])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer, however i'm now getting another error and I don't know how to fix it, i tryied several thing but all ended up with that error : 
main.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')
    at attribute_for_you (main.js:69:23)
    at main.js:72:1

Comment: You haven't added those image elements to your DOM. By the way, I updated my answer for the sake of your change @GuillaumeMaugin

Comment: That's really cool, thanks for your help :) However, eventhough the image element exist (At least for the first one), it won't apply the src property to the element. Here is some more screenshot : [link](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/15xOWczvYRfovydGsTUExB3tN8iMdHwq82ymwBSbyg-Q/edit?usp=sharing) Thx a lot for your time

Comment: I don't have the access to your link, could you grant me that access? @GuillaumeMaugin

Comment: here it is ! :)

Comment: That error I only get once I don't have that element in HTML. You can play it here https://jsfiddle.net/ubx3rkwf/. I think you should share how you integrate with HTML too @GuillaumeMaugin

Answer (score 0):

> var img_index = document.getElementsById(index_for_you[i])

`getElementById` is use to get the html elements with specific id but you are using this to get your JS variable, that's not how it works so it will show error.